# PHP - Looking for an HTML Generator/Manager

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to find a tool that I can use to generate markup programatically (non-irl word). Here is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish in pseudo-code...

```
$htmlDoc = new HTML_Document();

$htmlDoc->setTitle('Cool Title');

$htmlDoc->addJs('some_js_file.js');
$htmlDoc->addStylesheet('some_css_file.css');

$divElement = new HTML_Element_Div();
$htmlDoc->append('body', $divElement);

$output = $htmlDoc->generate();
```

What is the best tool for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's one bundled as standard in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

C.

Answer (score 5):

I'm working on a simple DSL that addresses this common task. It's called **htmlgen**, mirrored on [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/z1ffy/htmlgen).

Here's an example -

```
use function htmlgen\html as h;

h('#wrapper',
  h('h1.title', 'Hello, World'),
  h('p',
    h('comment', 'link to something'),
    h('a', ['href'=>'https://duckduckgo.com'], 'search the internet')
  )
);
```

Here's the output (actual output does not have whitespace)

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1 class="title">Hello, World</h1>
  <p>
    <!-- link to something -->
    <a href="https://duckduckgo.com">search the internet</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

It's very new but at ~200 lines of source, it's already very powerful. Fork it and make adjustments or send me a note with suggestions.

Comment: Loving that subInject method!

Answer (score 2):

Writing your own simple framework is very simple and is a great learning experience.  You can implement this in merely an hour or two, in fact I just did for a recent project only a couple weeks ago.

What I recommend is:

1. Create a simple .HTML template with placeholder tags, I use the syntax %HTML_TITLE% and your setTitle method simple does a STR-REPLACE.
2. The same holds true for JS, CSS
3. Since you may not add certain pieces everytime it's important than it your generate() function you remove any remaining %% tags with a %\w+% regex.

Comment: I'm building a framework based off kohana's cascading file system. I want to delegate many of the framework libraries (layout, db persistence, input, etc...) to well-known, mature, libraries. Thanks for the good suggestion though!

Comment: +1 for learning through doing.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not aware of such a library, but it would be quite easy to write one, for example, based on [XMLWriter](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php).

That said, it's worth noting that php was especially designed to avoid things like this. I'd suggest a templating engine or even 'pure' php for html output.